# How use app.use in io.on?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

How I can use app.use in socket.io? E.g.

```
io.on('connection', function(data){
    app.use('uri here', function(req, res){
        // emitting here
    });
});
```

It's really? 
I have:

```
ss1.example.com (head-server for caching online users with users servers).

ss2.example.com (first app server)

ss3.example.com (second app server)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Socket.io has `io.use` if you want to use middleware.

Comment: Please provide some more details on the end results. It also depends on how you have `app` configured. For example, I have `var app = express();` so `app.use` is never inside the socket.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding something here.  The sequence of events when a web page is loaded is as follows:

1. User initiates page load (by clicking on something or by typing something in the URL bar or by selecting a bookmark).
2. Browser parses the server, gets the host and port out of the URL and sends an http GET request for the path to the IP address for that host and port.
3. Web server receives the GET request and sends back to the browser an HTML page.
4. The web server may or may not use middleware when that request is received (depending upon what it wants to do).
5. Browser parses the HTML page and then runs scripts in the page.
6. Javascript in the web page runs and initiates socket.io connection to some host (often to the same host that the web page came from).
7. Web server receives socket.io request and socket.io handle recognizes the web request as a socket.io connection request.
8. Server-side socket.io code responds to client request for socket.io connection and a socket.io connection is initiated between browser and server.
9. Client or server can then send data over the socket.io connection.

Now, to your question about where to insert `app.use()`.  That is for http middleware.  You would insert that in the regular web server request chain, typically right before you `app.get()` and `app.post()` request handlers.  You would not typically use http middleware for a socket.io connection.

If you wish to run some code before any socket.io connection connects, then you would use `io.use()` and use a socket.io middleware handler.  That will give you access to the http request information on every socket.io connection request.

If you wish to run some code on every socket.io message that is received (regardless of the message name), that is not a supported feature of socket.io.  There are some add-ons that hack into socket.io to allow you to essentially do a `socket.on('*', ...)` type event handler for all incoming socket.io messages, but that is not something that socket.io supports as a built-in feature.

If one of these options still doesn't sound like what you want, then please explain to use what actual problem you're trying to solve and we can better make a suggestion for that particular problem.

---

Note your question is a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you asked how to do what you think is the solution (using `app.use()` for socket.io) rather than describing the actual problem you want to solve.  The problem with that type of question is that if you're wrong about the solution direction, then all we can really tell you is that you're wrong with that solution because you didn't describe the actual problem so we can direct you to the right type of solution.  In the future, you will probably get better answers if you make sure to describe the problem you're trying to solve, not just the solution you're trying.